# Share news articles between sites

Tags: kentico

Does anyone know if it is possible to share data between sites on a Kentico platform, such as news articles? I have tried searching but could not find an answer.

Thank you,

Comment: Are these articles and news to be shared are for the two websites on the same Kentico instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you want the content to be the same and keep the URLs and Domains separate, then this is best accomplished with linked documents between the sites. This way if they are updated on either site, they will remain in sync on the other site. Read more here: https://docs.kentico.com/k9/managing-website-content/working-with-pages/copying-and-moving-pages-creating-linked-pages

https://docs.kentico.com/k9/e-commerce-features/managing-your-store/products/linking-existing-products-or-sections

Basically what you'd want to do in your content tree, is click "new page" and then select "Link an existing page" from the bottom of the next menu. After that, you will see a content tree to select a page from. Use the site selector in the top left to choose a different site, and then select the page you'd like to link in.

Note: Keep in mind that the page type will need to be allowed in that section of the tree (for example, if you are trying to nest a news article under a folder but folders are not an allowed parent type, you will get an error).

---

If you'd like to pull data from another site in via repeater and leave the content on the other site, then you can user a repeater or similar viewer control, and specify a site within the properties in order to pull the pages from the other site.

Each of these methods assumes the Kentico sites are on the same instance of Kentico with a shared database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple sites in one Kentico instance, in your repeater getting the news articles, specify the site you want to get the news articles from and it will be displayed on that site.  If you want to combine them then create a custom query and use the query repeater to show the news articles.